# AWS Dynamo DB - How can I set the TTL to a default value of 7 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking to set up TTL on my DynamoDB so that I can expire items from some of the tables.

I worked out how to enable the TTL and set an attribute on the table with an Epoch value of when the TTL will expire and it works, however this is not manageable as I assume that this requires me to manually add this attribute and epoch value every time?

Can anyone advise if it is possible to set the TTL to a default value of 7 days and how I can automatically have this to delete items from tables after the 7 days?

Thanks

Eamon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone advise if it is possible to set the TTL to a default value of 7 days...

No - you will have to set this every time (which should be trivial to calculate) in your DynamoDB request.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute that has a value of the current timestamp plus 7 days to each new item that is created in the table. Configure DynamoDB to use the attribute as the TTL attribute.